# How to import main javascript file content (classes and constants) on test file in replit

Tags: replit

I received a task for a job application for refactoring a javascript code and writing some tests. The main file is sut.js and test file is sut.test.js on replit. In sut.test.js there was default test and this line at the top of the file

```
const { sum } = require('./sut')
```

I tried to add import statements but I could not reach my class and constants in the main file.

```
import {x, y} from './sut.js';
```

Currently, I just copy paste my all file content to sut.test.js file to write my tests. I could not find proper information to do this simple thing. This is the first time I use split.com and I already spend more than half an hour for this simple issue. Any help will be appreciated. For tests, jest is used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

I added this to at the bottom of my main js file which has constants and class.

```
 module.exports = {type, typeGroup, typeInfo, typeGroupInfo, reportTitles,  ExpensesLibrary };
```

Then I added this line to at the top of the test.js file

```
const { type, typeGroup, typeInfo, typeGroupInfo, reportTitles,  ExpensesLibrary }  = require('./sut')
```